# Some textures missing after exporting to Gltf

Tags: export, three.js

I made this scene in blender following a youtube tutorial:
[image]

As you see there are lots of planes, this is grass, which was a Particle System before but I decided to convert it to mesh in order to export it (before converting it was not exporting). Now, after converting the grass to mesh, I see that the grass material is not present in the GLTF viewer model.

This is how the textures should be:

**Rendered:**

[image]

**Material view:**

[image]

And this is how it looks in the browser:

**https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ :**
[image]

The white cube in the middle is a cube that I made to see what was the problem; I assigned to it the same material that the grass and it doesn't show up either in the browser with three.js

**Blend file link:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e9j0CSp7bxmwITFIPL8dwE-w39k5IL7L/view?usp=sharing

Comment: According to the manual, you'd have to use a principled shader for all objects: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html

Comment: I did change every shader so they are all principled but nothing changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grass uses a procedural texture (*Noise Texture* node). You can't export procedural textures. All the nodes work only inside of Blender. You need an image texture.

The use of the *Principled BSDF* just tells the exporter which standard slots are used (diffuse, normal, roughness, metal, etc) and which image textures are assigned.

If you want to export a procedural texture to a game engine or external 3D viewer then you need to **bake the texture** to an image.

[image: gtlf-viewer]
(The texture of the bridge was not included in your blend file and I was lazy and applied the modifiers to only one floating rock.)